# A HEAD call to a CFC always returns a 500 (CF11)

Tags: coldfusion, httprequest, httpresponse, coldfusion-11

I have certain processes running daily from third parties and it is not possible to change them.
In short, these processes hit several of our CFCs with a simple HEAD type call.
Those processes always get a 500 Internal Server Error.
Any ideas guys?

The requests:

`curl --location --head https://example.com/bla/sample.cfc?method=test`

`<cfhttp method="head" url="https://example.com/bla/sample.cfc?method=test">`

The first request is the one made by the third party, the second one is a test from my Coldfusion 11, both requests receive the same answer:

`HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error`

If I make the same request using GET, I receive an "OK" as a response for both requests, as expected.

The sample.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent output="false">    
    <cffunction name="test" access="remote" output="false" returntype="string" returnformat="plain">
        <cfreturn "OK">
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

The coldfusion-out.log:

```
[ajp-bio-8014-exec-4] - Starting HTTP request {URL='https://example.com/bla/sample.cfc?method=test', method='head'}
[ajp-bio-8014-exec-4] - HTTP request completed  {Status Code=500 ,Time taken=274 ms}
```

The coldfusion-error.log:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [CFCServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/NoBodyResponse
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.doHead(HttpServlet.java:245)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:437)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

There is no alert in the exception.log or server.log files.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: This is for ColdFusion 10 right? You said so in yer post on CFWheels github discussions. That is important info to include (and tag with). Looks to me like you can't catch it cos CF is barfing at Tomcat's request even before handing it over to the app code. Question: are these .cfc URLs set up as REST endpoints, or are you just getting the auto-gen API docs with your GET requests to same? Or are the URLs more like https://example.com/path/to/My.cfc?method=someMethod&etc ?

Comment: @adam-cameron, thanks for your feedback.
I added the Coldfusion 10 tag, thanks for your recommendation.
I also simplified the post and added information you requested. To summarize, the same request to a cfc method returns different responses, depending if the request is GET or HEAD ("200 OK" vs "500 Internal Server Error")

Comment: As Adrian suggested in his answer, these requests should be answered by the web server. Not ColdFusion.

Comment: @Miguel-F not necessarily. A HEAD req is expected to send the same headers as a GET response, and those might be derived from the application code. There's nothing special about a HEAD req that suggests it's a webserver-only thing.

Comment: @ArielMaioli is this specific to CFC-requests? How does it go on just .cfm one? Sorry I don't have CF10 to test on; but out-of-the-box CF2021 has no problems with an example like yours, so it's not like it's *innately* not possible. I'll try to find someone with CF10 running who can check...

Comment: I managed to find someone else using CF10 and they replicated your situation and it worked fine. So I suspect it's some Tomcat misconfig on your end, unfortunately. Would still be good to hear back re .cfm requests though.

Comment: @adam-cameron Yes, this is specific to CFC-requests, for .cfm the responses are always as expected, i.e. HTTP/1.1 200 OK.
Thanks!

Comment: @adam-cameron let me know if you need more information or details to help me!

Comment: For that particular class to not be found, I'm wondering if some libraries have been added to or updated in your ColdFusion/Tomcat installation, such that there's a rogue version of the servlet API JAR on the classpath causing a version mismatch. In the versions of HttpServlet.java I've looked at, NoBodyResponse is a private nested class -- but the error says it is looking javax/servlet/http/NoBodyResponse which is a not nested in HttpServlet.

Comment: @sean-corfield Interesting what you say... I honestly don't know if any libraries were added or updated but I'll look into that!

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to configure request filters in your IIS settings.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/configure-request-filtering-in-iis

You can try to reject all `HEAD` requests to `.cfc` file extensions.

Also, you should have all of your CFC methods that accept remote requests validate the request is either a `GET` or `POST` as expected. You don't want any function call that updates data from a form post to allow a `GET`. That could unexpectedly expose information to attackers.

Comment: Thanks @adrian-j-moreno, all methods accept remote requests and I verify that they are valid requests.
But for this case, I need to NOT reject HEAD requests. These requests are made directly to the CFC (without any method)
I will try to test your recommendation with filters in IIS.